# Options on host a RabbitMQ consumer C# script / console app (.exe) that invokes once and run continuously

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, .net-core, console-application, hosting

I need looking for cloud options to host a .net core console app (.exe). The app connects to RabbitMQ server, listen to a queue, consume some messages and do something. The console app just need to be invoke once, and it run continuously on it's own.

Currently the options I reviewed

- Azure Webjobs
- Azure functions
- AWS lambda

It seems to me that Azure Webjobs is the most viable option. AWS lambda and Azure functions are more suited for situation when the app is triggered by events or schedule.

Are there any other better options for my requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

You can publish your app on Kubernetes azure, where you can configure an object of several type including one expecific called DEPLOYMENT, this way you can´t need to change your application console.